# Is the boundary of a manifold always compact?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Coming from a background of undergrad physics training, I know that "the boundary of a boundary is zero".
Does this mean that the boundary of a manifold is always compact(or maybe just closed)?

Keep in mind that some of the terminology that mathematicians use might not be familiar to me due to my aforementioned background.
Thank you.

Note: This question arises from my reading of the anti De-Sitter spacetime which has a compactified Minkowski spacetime as its boundary.

EDIT: How about the boundary of a compact manifold?

Comment: Consider $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3;\,z \leq x^{2}+y^2\}$. Its boundary is the manifold $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3};z=x^{2}+y^{2}\}$, which is not compact.

Comment: The boundary is a closed subset, so if the manifold is compact...

Comment: Consider an infinite solid cylinder.   Boundary is an infinite cylinder.   Closed but not bounded.  So not compact by heine-borel...

Comment: No. The points $(x,y)$ in the plane with $x\ge 0$ form a manifold with boundary. The boundary in the $y$-axis and this is not compact.

Answer (score 5):

A manifold with boundary is locally like a half space (e.g. upper half plane if in dimension 2). As such, any topological properties will be inherited. Indeed, you can see that the boundary of a half space is a plane, which has empty boundary, and also is not compact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I also ask if the boundary of a compact manifold is a compact manifold itself?

Comment: In the subspace topology, yes, I think so. Take an open cover of the boundary $\partial M$. It extends to an open cover of the boundary in $M$, which extends to an open cover of $M$. $M$ is compact so there must be a finite subcover for $\partial M$.

Comment: We will need a definition of "manifold" in order to answer your new question.  One reason that new questions should be posted as questions, not as comments to answers.

Comment: @GEdgar What issues arise here? Is the general topological manifold not sufficient? If my answer was not correct I should amend this.

Comment: A "topological manifold" has no notion of boundary at all.  Perhaps TheQM means "manifold with boundary" in the technical sense, or perhaps something else.  I get the impression that TheQM does not know these definitions.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, you're right, I mean the following def: a Hausdorff space such that each point has neighborhood either homeomorphic to an open set in $R^n$, or homeomorphic to an open set in $R_{+}^n$.

Given your comment, are there any issues such as second countability, etc, that I have overlooked? I know some such conditions are often necessary but I'm not experienced enough to easily recognize where they are needed.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed, I do not know these definitions. I am having a bit of a hard time here, so please excuse me for not being precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $\mathbb R^n $ itself embedded in the " Standard Way" in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ as $(x_1,x_2,..,x_n,0): x_i \in \mathbb R$. It is itself a manifold with boundary -- and every point is a boundary point -- but it is not compact, since it is not bounded -- you can even let a single coordinate grow as much as you want it to , to argue for unboundedness.

Answer (score 1):

In general no, but if you have the added assertion that you're manifold $M$ is compact, then it's boundary $\partial M$ is also compact.

*Proof:* If $M$ is a compact $n$-manifold with boundary $\partial M$. It is a well-known theorem that $\partial M$ is closed in $M$, therefore since any closed subset of a compact space is compact, it follows that $\partial M$ is compact. $\square$

As you can see, it is a well known theorem that for any manifold $M$, $\partial M$ is closed in $M$ equipped with the subspace topology.